# Fechar Activity anterior torna o aplicativo mais rápido?

Tags: android, android-activity

Eu estava desenvolvendo uma aplicação para Android e me surgiu uma duvida:

Na minha classe principal `MainActivity` eu tenho a função `setContentView` que inicializa a minha tela, mas se eu quiser abrir outras `Activity` preciso fechar as anteriores para que o aplicativo fique mais rápido?

É uma dúvida boba mas quero saber se o aplicativo ganha performance fechando as *views* anteriores.

Answer (score 3):

Tornar um app mais otimizado, requer várias preparativos além de fechar activitys anteriores. Pela lógica, ao fechar uma activity anterior, libera memória e pode ajudar no processamento. Mas só isso não basta. Refaça a lógica de funcionamento do app, pode ser que vc tenha esteja criajno muitas activitys, e vc poderia agrupar as funções em poucas telas... Outra coisa, pode ajudar, é diminuir a criação de cópias de variáveis enquanto o app esta rodando. O carregamento de imagens e dependências de recursos através da internet, podem fazer seu app parecer lento, onde na verdade estaria fazendo download de dados.

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

É bem provavel que fique, mas se você precisar voltar para a activity anterior vai precisar fazer uma Intent.